# mySQL php form not saving data

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am trying to use the following php form however every time I get the error message ***Saving Failed Please Print Data...***

I presume this means its connecting to the database fine however the data isn't getting either to the php file or to the database correctly. any pointers would be great...

Thanks

Henry

**new_client.html form**

```
<form id="form_956123" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="new_client.php">
                <div class="form_description">
        <h2>New Client</h2>
        <p>Please enter your client details below</p>
    </div>                      
        <ul >

                <li id="li_1" >
    <label class="description" for="firstname">First Name </label>
    <div>
        <input id="firstname" name="firstname" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div> 
    </li>       <li id="li_2" >
    <label class="description" for="lastname">Last Name </label>
    <div>
        <input id="lastname" name="lastname" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div> 
    </li>       <li id="li_3" >
    <label class="description" for="address">Address </label>
    <div>
        <textarea id="address" name="address" class="element textarea medium"></textarea> 
    </div> 
    </li>       <li id="li_4" >
    <label class="description" for="postcode">Postcode </label>
    <div>
        <input id="postcode" name="postcode" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div> 
    </li>       <li id="li_5" >
    <label class="description" for="email">Email </label>
    <div>
        <input id="email" name="email" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div> 
    </li>       <li id="li_6" >
    <label class="description" for="tel">Phone </label>
    <div>
        <input id="tel" name="tel" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div> 
    </li>       <li id="li_7" >
    <label class="description" for="dob">Date of Birth </label>
    <div>
        <input id="dob" name="dob" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div> 
    </li>

          <li class="buttons">
            <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="956123" />

            <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </li>
      </ul>
    </form>
```

**new_client.php**

```
<?php //Post Params 
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];  
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];  
$address = $_POST['address'];  
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];  
$email = $_POST['email'];  
$dob = $_POST['dob'];  
$tel = $_POST['tel'];  
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO client_data (date, userid, firstname, lastname, address, postcode, email, dob, tel) VALUES (NOW(), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssss",$firstname,$firstname,$lastname,$address,$postcode,$email,$dob,$tel);
$stmt->execute();

echo "New records created successfully";

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

**TABLE FORMAT**

```
Column  Type    
date    date    
userid  text
firstname   text
lastname    text
address text
postcode    text
email   text
dob text
tel  text
```

Comment: You're mixing mysql and mysqli. You can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:

```
mysql_query($query)
```

For one, you can't mix `mysql_` and `mysqli_`. Secondly, if you are working procedural-style, you have to specify the connection in the first parameter (i.e. `mysqli_query($conn, $query)`, or OO-style: `$conn->query`).

However, since you're dealing with strings, you need to use prepared statements to avoid SQL injections. The CORRECT way to do it is this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO client_data ( date, userid, firstname, lastname, address, postcode, email, dob, tel )  VALUES (NOW(), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,  ? ) "));
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssss",$firstname,$firstname,$lastname,$address,$postcode,$email,$dob,$tel);
$stmt->execute();
```

By the way, why is `userid` not an ID?

**UPDATE:** Change your code to this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO client_data ( date, userid, firstname, lastname, address, postcode, email, dob, tel )  VALUES (NOW(), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,  ? ) "));
if ( false===$stmt ) { die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error)); }
$rc = $stmt->bind_param("ssssssss",$firstname,$firstname,$lastname,$address,$postcode,$email,$dob,$tel);
if ( false===$rc ) { die('bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error)); }
$rc = $stmt->execute();
if ( false===$rc ) { die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error)); }
```

And tell me what output you're getting.

Comment: the user ID is a memorable id which will be specified by the user not a unique integer

Comment: i'm struggling to get my head round the syntax of all this... I might start from scratch... don't suppose you have an example with just one field in I could look at? i then might be able to peice my head round it all

Comment: @HenryAspden Prepared statements you mean? http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: actually, it came back with a nice confirmation but not data was saved... updated code above now

Comment: Oh by the way, I accidentally linked you to `pdo`s prepared statements.

Comment: @HenryAspden First parameter shouldn't be a question mark, it should be `NOW()`.

Comment: @HenryAspden See my update and tell me what you see.

Comment: ahhh it's working now thanks @Shahar!!! No for my next trick.. how would one go about having the userID assigned as a sequential ID?

Comment: @HenryAspden You would have to change your database, make the ID an auto increment int (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp). Once you do that, remove the parameter from the SQL statement (so that means get rid of userid and one question mark from the prepare statement and one $firstname from the bind_param statement).

Comment: Also, the userid should be a primary key.

Comment: tried this and had a few issues wierdly... so anyhow decided i want the userid to be a string made up of firstnamelastnamedob how would i best go about this? create a new variable at the top? as $userid = $_POST['firstname''lastname''dob']; ?

Comment: sorry $userid = $_POST['firstname'] . $_POST['lastname'] . $_POST['dob'];

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are connecting with mysql and querying with mysqli and not specifying the db connection.

Try:

```
$result = mysli_query($conn, $query);
```

Comment: didn't seem to do much unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

to

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

or use a prepared statement (recommended).

Then, if it is still not working, change

```
echo 'Saving Failed Please Print Data...';
```

to

```
echo mysqli_error($conn);
```

temporarily to see if it will say what the error is.

Comment: currently its returning a blank page now

Comment: you're gonna laugh... looks like my FTP manage was goosed... tryng again now

Comment: i think i need to start again

Comment: ahh i've started from scratch and am trying to follow Shahar's method now

Answer (score -1):

```
 $query = " INSERT INTO client_data ( date, userid, firstname, lastname, address, postcode, email, dob, tel )  VALUES ( 'now()','','$firstname', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$address', '$postcode', '$email', '$dob',  '$tel' ) ";
```

or try this

```
 $query = " INSERT INTO client_data ( date, firstname, lastname, address, postcode, email, dob, tel )  VALUES ( 'now()','$firstname', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$address', '$postcode', '$email', '$dob',  '$tel' ) ";
```

i assumed the userid field is auto increment.

then change this line

```
$mysql->query($query);
```

to

```
$mysqli->query($query);
```

Comment: (date, userid, firstname,)VALUES ( 'now()','its for userid','$firstname')

Comment: do you think no spaces then?

Comment: what do you mean with no space?

Comment: i want the user ID to be the first name (for now) and other than changing that you just deleted the spaces...

Comment: well, is 'userid' type varchar ? in you table

Comment: i presumes you mean $result = mysql_query($query); line to be $result = mysqli_query($query);